# Perfect numbers whose number of divisors is also perfect

Tags: number-theory

A [perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) is a number for which the sum of its divisors is equal to twice the number itself. Prove that 28 is the only perfect number whose number of divisors is also a (necessarily even) perfect number, regardless of whether odd perfect numbers exist or not. For even perfect numbers, one might use the result that they must be of the form $2^{p-1} * (2^p-1)$ where $2^p-1$ is a Mersenne prime. For odd perfect numbers (should they exist), one might use the known result by Euler that any such number must be of the form ${p}^{a} * {n}^{2}$ where $p \equiv a \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $p$ is an odd prime.

Comment: Please provide some context for this question, in particular where it comes from, but also show at least some of what you've tried yourself.

Comment: Do you know the general form of even perfects, Geoffrey? Can you then work out how many divisors such a number has? And then can you see why that number can't be perfect?

Comment: I neither understand why this question should not contain context (the criterion of Euler is given) nor the reason for the downvote (I guess because I answered a poor question, I have no idea what else it can be)

Comment: @peter Your answer was downvoted because in addition to containing an obvious typo (tiwce [sic]), it also does not mention the number 28 explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

First the even case : An even perfect number has the form $$2^{k-1}\cdot (2^k-1)$$ where $2^k-1$ is a Mersenne prime , that implies that $k$ must be prime as well. Hence with the exception $k=2$ , $k$ must be odd. The number of divisors of the above number is $2k$, hence $4$ or twice an odd number. The only such perfect number is $6$, which gives $k=3$ corresponding with the number $28$

Now to the odd case.

The number of disivors of $p^a\cdot n^2$ is $(a+1)$ times an odd number,and since $a+1$ is twice an odd number, the only possibility is that the number of divisors is $6$ , which means $a=1$ and $n$ prime. Hence we have the number $p\cdot n^2$ with odd primes $p$ and $n$

If $pn^2$ would be perfect, we would have $$(p+1)(n^2+n+1)=2pn^2$$

But the functions $$f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x}$$ and $$g(x)=\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2}$$ for $x\ge 3$ have the global maximums $\frac{4}{3}$ ($f(x)$)  and $\frac{13}{9}$ ($g(x)$)  , the product of those is smaller than $2$, hence the above equality cannot hold.

Comment: Note I didn't down vote. However, as the OP commented, you may wish to state your original $n=3$ gives $28$. Also, your statement of "... the only possibility is $n=6$" is confusing as it's not the $n$ from before, but the product of $(a + 1)$ & the odd number you referred to before. In addition, you don't mention or handle the case of $a = 5$ & $n = 1$. Perhaps it's not allowed in Euler's result, but the OP doesn't mention it. However, it's easy to handle as, for it to be perfect requires $p^5 + p^4 + p^3 + p^2 + p + 1 = 2p^5$,  but $p$ divides the right side although not the left side.

Comment: It's now better. However, I mentioned $2$ other things in my previous comment (plus there's also the typo of "tiwce") but I suggest you at least also fix the one of "... the only possibility is $n = 6$" part as it's *not* $n$ which is $6$ (you state just afterwards that $n$ is prime) but the product of $(a + 1)$ and the odd number (i.e., of the # of factors of $n^2$).

Comment: I prefer to not edit other people's answers, so I don't do it very often and generally, when I do, it's only to fix very small, obvious typo type errors. This is because if people don't check carefully, they assume everything is written by the person who answered the question, so I don't want to have it be phrased differently. As there's more than one way to change the wording to fix the "$n = 6$" error, and I wasn't sure how you would prefer to make that change, I didn't want to do it myself.

Comment: @JohnOmielan In the case, there is still an issue with the "twice", I would like to know what is wrong. "$4$ or twice an odd number" is a valid formulation, to my opnion , meaning "$2,4,6,10,14,\cdots$"

Comment: The issue is just with the spelling, i.e, it's written as "tiwce" instead of "twice", which is why I stated it was a typo. Also, this occurs for the odd case, i.e., $2$ paragraphs down. This is something I could have edited myself, but as I thought you were going to change your answer anyway, I thought I'd let you do it instead. Nonetheless, as you can see, I've just edited your answer to fix this.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Seems that the heat here causes some problems with the concentration. Thank you for the edit.